# How to test a checkbox is checked in angular unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular8

Hi there I am using a checkbox to be pretend as a toggle button with the help of CSS. The function is simple when the checkbox is true it enables the toggle button and vice versa. I want to check that in my unit test. I know I'm missing something on the below code. Any help would be appreciated

**Test**

```
it('should toggle switch to on if user response equals true', fakeAsync(() => {
    spectator.get(service).user.and.returnValue({});
    spyOn(spectator.get(serivce2), 'method').and.returnValue({Payload: {success: true}});
    tick();
    spectator.detectChanges();
    expect(spectator.query('.toggle-button').getAttribute('checked')).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `.toggle-button` is on an `<input type="checkbox">`. You can use `spectator.query('.toggle-button').checked` which is standard HTML DOM API.

Answer (score 0):

try this  by getting the **nativeElement**

```
expect(spectator.query('.toggle-button').nativeElement.getAttribute('checked')).toBeTruthy();
```